# How to fill ViewModel which has List<T> property after clicking submit button mvc 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to make a day of the week checkbox using a viewModel.  Everything is ok on the View, but, if I click submit to save changes, `weeklySchedule` within my httppost method is null.

Why is `weeklySchedule` null?  How would I send the selected checkbox value to my `HttPost` action? Any advice would help.

[image]

**Model:**

```
public class Settings
{
    public class WeeklySetting
    {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**View Model:**

```
public class ViewModels
{
    public class Weekly
    {
        public List&#60;Settings.WeeklySetting&#62; Settings { get; set; }
    }
}


public ActionResult CreateWeekly()
   {
       var model = new ViewModels.Weekly
       {
             Settings = new[] 
             {
             new Settings.WeeklySetting{ DisplayName="Monday", Value="MON", IsChecked=false},
             new Settings.WeeklySetting{ DisplayName="Tuesday", Value="TUE", IsChecked=false},
             new Settings.WeeklySetting{ DisplayName="Wednesday", Value="WED", IsChecked=false},
             new Settings.WeeklySetting{ DisplayName="Thursday", Value="THU", IsChecked=false},
             new Settings.WeeklySetting{ DisplayName="Friday", Value="FRI", IsChecked=false},
             new Settings.WeeklySetting{ DisplayName="Saturday", Value="SAT", IsChecked=false},
              new Settings.WeeklySetting{ DisplayName="Sunday", Value="SUN", IsChecked=false},
            }.ToList()
       };
           return View(model);

   }
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult CreateWeekly(string submitButton, ViewModels.Weekly weeklySchedule)
   {

    //Do something
       return View("CreateWeekly", weeklySchedule);
   }
```

**View:**

`<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyProject.Controllers.ViewModels.Weekly>" %>`

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    CreateWeekly
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<% using (Html.BeginForm())
      { %>

```
  &#60;div&#62;
  &#60;%foreach (var item in Model.Settings)
    {%&#62;

        &#60;%:Html.CheckBoxFor(q=&#62;item.IsChecked) %&#62;
        &#60;%:Html.LabelFor(q=&#62;item.IsChecked,item.DisplayName) %&#62;
        &#60;%:Html.HiddenFor(q=&#62;item.Value) %&#62;
   &#60;% } %&#62;

  &#60;/div&#62;
&#60;br /&#62;
   &#60;input value="GenerateForWeekly" name="submitButton" type="submit" /&#62;
      &#60;%} %&#62;
```

</asp:Content>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model binding doesn't work very nicely when you start using foreach() { } loops in your view.  If you use an EditorTemplate for WeeklySetting you'll find it works much better as it sorts out all the indices for you.

E.g. (this is MVC3 Razor view syntax)

(1) Create an editor template for WeeklySetting:

```
@model Settings.WeeklySetting
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsChecked)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsChecked,Model.DisplayName)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DisplayName)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Value)
```

(2) Render in your view with an EditorFor (no foreach):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Settings)
    </div>
    <br />
    <input value="GenerateForWeekly" name="submitButton" type="submit" />
}
```

Comment: but i must use asp.net mvc 3 :(

Comment: @programmerist My code is for asp.net mvc3, that only difference is that you are using the ASPX view engine instead of the Razor view engine.  The principle is the same.

Comment: Sorry but how to design Editor template

Comment: i wrote my code is the same as your link:  coding-in.net/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-editortemplates. i can not see any differences.

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you use a `for` loop instead of `foreach`.
As shown here:
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx