# How to solve System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added in mvc 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

i created ViewModel to test this answer : [How to fill ViewModel which has List<T> property after clicking submit button mvc 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360795/how-to-fill-viewmodel-which-has-listt-property-after-clicking-submit-button-mv)

i need checkboxlist look please WeeklyModel.Also WeeklyViewModel. i want to list alldoays in checkboxes. Nut my error below . it is stupid error. i can not understand reson to solve how to solve it? thanks...
Look please helpful ( what i need artcile) article : [When do I use View Models, Partials, Templates and handle child bindings with MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157348/when-do-i-use-view-models-partials-templates-and-handle-child-bindings-with-mv)
Models:

```
   public class WeeklyModel

        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Value { get; set; }
            public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
        }


       public class WeeklyViewModel
        {
            public IEnumerable<WeeklyModel> Settings { get; set; }
            public WeeklyViewModel()
            {
                Settings = new List<WeeklyModel>();
            }

        }
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult CreateWeekly()
       {
           var model = new WeeklyViewModel();
            List<WeeklyModel> li = new List<WeeklyModel>();
            li.Add( new WeeklyModel(){ Name="Monday", Value="mon", IsChecked=false});
            model.Settings = li;
               return View(model);
       }
       [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateWeekly( WeeklyViewModel weekly)
       {

           return View("CreateWeekly", weekly);
       }
```

i created Views/Trigger/EditorTemplates/WeeklyModels.aspx :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/ChildSite.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<GenSystem.Models.WeeklyModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<%:Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.IsChecked) %>
<%:Html.LabelFor(m=>m.IsChecked,Model.Name) %>
<%:Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Name) %>
<%:Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Value) %>

</asp:Content>
```

View :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/ChildSite.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<GenSystem.Models.WeeklyViewModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    CreateWeekly
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<% 

    using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
          %>

      <div>
     <%:Html.EditorFor(m => m.Settings)%>
      </div>
    <br />
       <input value="GenerateForWeekly" name="submitButton" type="submit" />
          <%} %>
</asp:Content>
```

How to solve this Error:

System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
at Transformer.NET.Token.ParseAnchors()
at Transformer.NET.TextTransformer.Parse(List`1 tokensType, Dictionary`2 variables)
at Transformer.NET.TextTransformer.Transform(List`1 tokensType, Dictionary`2 variables)
at Transformer.NET.TextTransformer.Transform(List`1 tokensType)
at Transformer.NET.TextTransformer.Transform()
at Ext.Net.ExtNetTransformer.Transform(String text)
at Ext.Net.InitScriptFilter.Transform()
at Ext.Net.InitScriptFilter.Flush()
at System.Web.HttpWriter.Filter(Boolean finalFiltering)
at System.Web.HttpResponse.FilterOutput()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallFilterExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editor templates should be `.ascx` controls, not `.aspx` pages. Also your file is wrongly named. It is named `WeeklyModels.aspx` but the correct name is `WeeklyModel.ascx` (without `s`) because your class is called `WeeklyModel` and not `WeeklyModels`.

So inside `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/WeeklyModel.ascx` you could put the following:

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<GenSystem.Models.WeeklyModels>" 
%>
<%= Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsChecked) %>
<%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsChecked, Model.Name) %>
<%= Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name) %>
<%= Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Value) %>
```

and inside your main view `CreateWeekly.aspx`:

```
<%@ Page 
    Title="" 
    Language="C#" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/ChildSite.Master" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<GenSystem.Models.WeeklyViewModel>" 
%>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    CreateWeekly
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
        <div>
            <%= Html.EditorFor(m => m.Settings) %>
        </div>
        <br />
        <input value="GenerateForWeekly" name="submitButton" type="submit" />
    <% } %>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: thanks working but a little bit question: <%@ Control  Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<GenSystem.Models.WeeklyModels>" %>
 why drawing underline blue and say : Statement cannot appear outside of method body /multiline lambda

Comment: Thanks again.This ascx not underline blue: <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="GenSystem.Views.Shared.EditorTemplates.WebUserControl1" %>